# Yii2 Imagine сохранение изображения с русскими символами

Tags: yii2

Собственно вопрос в названии темы. К примеру есть файл `картинка.jpg`, после сохранения остается только `jpg` Т.е. вырезаются все русские буквы.

Сам файл сохраняется корректно, т.е. если просто загрузить на сервер.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще не советую делать загрузку картинок с русскими буквами,
советую все хешировать в md5.

Про загрузку я писал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536032/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-yii2) .