# Прикрепление изображения к постам yii2

Tags: yii2, изображения

Подскажите как правильно добавлять изображение к записи, сохранять в папку и выводить у записи при редактировании. Нужно создать отдельную модель или можно все это сделать в моделе поста?

Покажите пожалуйста примером...

**Модель поста**:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['category_id', 'status', 'author_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
        [['name'], 'required'],
        [['content'], 'string'],
        [['name', 'slug', 'description'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'], // добавили правило  для изображения
        [['author_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['author_id' => 'id']],
        [['category_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Category::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['category_id' => 'id']],
    ];
}
```

**Представление**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput() ?>
```

**Контроллер**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Course();
    $model->status = 1;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обычной загрузки фотографии я использую [этот виджет](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput)

Добавляете в модель

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['image'], 'safe'],
        [['image'], 'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png'],
    ];
}
```

Вешайте на события вот такой код

```
    public function afterDelete()
    {
        @unlink(Yii::getAlias('@uploads') . '/images/banner/' . $this->image);
        parent::afterDelete();
    }


/**
 * @param bool $insert
 * @return bool
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if(!parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'image')) {
        if (!$insert) {
            @unlink(Yii::getAlias('@uploads') . '/images/banner/' . $this->getOldAttribute('image'));
        }

        $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'image');
        $imageName = md5(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $pathImage = Yii::getAlias('@uploads') . '/images/banner/'
            . '/'
            . $imageName
            . '.'
            . $image->getExtension();

        $this->image =  $imageName .  '.' . $image->getExtension();
        $image->saveAs($pathImage);

    } else {
        $this->image = $this->getOldAttribute('image');
    }

    return true;

}
```

и view

```
    use kartik\file\FileInput;

    ...

    <?=  $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'showCaption' => false,
        'showRemove' => false,
        'showUpload' => false,
        'browseClass' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block',
        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
        'browseLabel' =>  'Select Photo'
    ],
]); ?>
```